# Computing weekly percent on grouped by table

Tags: sql, date

Good morning everybody.

I work on the last version of SQL Workbench.

I got a table group by Year and Week, and a type of document verification (3 at total).

| Year | Week | Verif_Type | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2020 | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 2020 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2020 | 2 | 2 | 6 |
| 2020 | 2 | 3 | 3 |

I want to know how many percent of each verification type are performed by week and year.

My question is there : How can I print the percent column next such that

| Year | Week | Verif_Type | Total | Percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 75 |
| 2020 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 25 |
| 2020 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 2020 | 2 | 2 | 6 | 60 |
| 2020 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 30 |

I have already computed total count per week but the table have different sizes, so I can't use operations with it.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: The last 3 entries should be Week 2 and the percentage in the 2nd entry should be 25%?

Comment: @404 You're right. I have edited

Comment: Please mention your dbms with version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MySql version 8.0 use Query#1 using windows function and for older version of MySQL use Query#2 (using subquery).

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table yourtable(Year int, Week int, Verif_Type int, Total int);
 insert into yourtable values(2020, 1,  1,  3);
 insert into yourtable values(2020, 1,  3,  1);
 insert into yourtable values(2020, 2,  1,  1);
 insert into yourtable values(2020, 2,  2,  6);
 insert into yourtable values(2020, 2,  3,  3);
```

Query#1 (using window function)

```
 Select year, week, verif_type, total, (total*100/sum(total)over(partition by year, week)) percent
     From yourtable
```

Output:

| year | week | verif_type | total | percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 75.0000 |
| 2020 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 25.0000 |
| 2020 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 10.0000 |
| 2020 | 2 | 2 | 6 | 60.0000 |
| 2020 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 30.0000 |

Query#2 (using subquery)

```
 select year, week, verif_type, total, (total*100/(select sum(total) from yourtable b where a.year=b.year and a.Week=b.Week)) percent
         From yourtable a
```

Output:

| year | week | verif_type | total | percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 75.0000 |
| 2020 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 25.0000 |
| 2020 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 10.0000 |
| 2020 | 2 | 2 | 6 | 60.0000 |
| 2020 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 30.0000 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8bf91bd2bb7ee26bf4448146318c0bd3)*

Comment: Nice query. Would add `Year` into the partition else it'll break when the table contains multiple years of data assuming week stands for week of the year.

Comment: Thank you , but like @404 says, my example go through 3 years. Do I have to change the query?

Comment: @404 thanks a lot. Yes year should be added in partition clause. I have revised my answer.